# Laravel get the last row for a user in related model

Tags: php, laravel

so i have relationship between three models:Users, Tickets and assigns.
A Ticket can have many users though assigns, so far I can retrieve all tickets that was assigned to the current user.

**AssignsTable**

```
id|ticket_id |user_id |created_at 
1 |30        |1       |2018-10-12 10:17:42
2 |30        |2       |2018-10-12 11:17:51
3 |31        |1       |2018-10-12 11:18:00
4 |32        |3       |2018-10-12 12:18:00  
5 |33        |1       |2018-10-12 12:30:00
```

**Query**

```
$tickets = Ticket::with('AssignedUsers')
           ->WhereHas('AssignedUsers', function($q) {
                $q->where('assigns.user_id', '=', '1')
                   ->latest('assigns.created_at')
                   ->groupBy('assigns.ticket_id')
                   ->orderBy('assigns.id');
             })
            ->get();
```

**Results**

```
id |ticket_id |user_id |created_at 
 1 |30        |1       |2018-10-12 10:17:42
 3 |31        |1       |2018-10-12 11:18:00
 5 |33        |1       |2018-10-12 12:30:00
```

**Expected Results**

```
id|ticket_id |user_id |created_at 
3 |31        |1       |2018-10-12 11:18:00   
5 |33        |1       |2018-10-12 12:30:00
```

As you can see above,I want to hide the ticket from user 1 in case it was assigned to another.

**Ticket Modal**

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    public function AssignedUsers() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'assigns','ticket_id','user_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Comment: to get the last row, why not order by id desc and limit 1?

Comment: i want to get all last tickets that was assigned to him not only the last one

Comment: How have you set up your Models?  You don't seem to be utilizing the eloquent ORM much at all.

Comment: No need for the -get() after ->first(), first "gets" the first result.

Comment: but the title of this question is 'Laravel get the last row for a user in related model'. maybe reword it if that's not actually what you want

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor english but i couldn't come up with something better

Answer (score 2):

First: You're doing an unnecessary extra subquery

Second: Try to use having with the group by, I didn't run the query, but I think it'll work

```
$tickets = Ticket::with(['AssignedUsers' => function($q){
    $q->where('assigns.user_id', '=', '1')
       ->latest('assigns.created_at')
       ->groupBy('assigns.ticket_id')
       ->orderBy('assigns.id')
       ->havingRaw('count(assigns.ticket_id) <= 1');
    }])
    ->get();
```

Comment: i get the following error, Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY, and i don't want to disable the only_full_group_by

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you want to retrive all the tickets that was assigned to a user you need to setup yout relations like:

```
use App\Ticket;
use App\User;

class Ticket extends Model
{
    /**
     * There is no need to explicitly put the foreign keys 
     * in the relation if there are named as the model
     */
    public function users() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'assigns')->withTimestamps()->withPivot(['id']);
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function tickets() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ticket::class, 'assigns')->withTimestamps()->withPivot(['id']);
    }
}
```

And accessing the  property "tickets" on a instance of a User model will retrive all the tickets assigned to him

```
$userTickets = User::find(1)->tickets; // will retrive ALL the records on 'AssignsTable' that have the field 'user_id' equals to 1
```

If you want to retrive all the tickets of the User::find(1) EXCEPT the first ticket (the ticket that have the id = 1) you need to explicitly exclude the id 1 in the query so:

```
$allUserTicketsExceptTheTicketWithId1 = User::find(1)->tickets()->wherePivot('id', '!=', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help, I appreciate your efforts.
I've found a solution by adding status field in assigns Table.

Thanks Again